How to upload annotation files via the CVAT REST API
I am trying to upload annotation files to the CVAT server using the REST API.Here is the code.
But the response of session.put(f'{cvat_url}/api/tasks/{task_id}/annotations/', files=files, params=params) is 403.
Is this code incorrect?
def upload_task_annotations(cvat_url, username, password, task_id, zip_file_path):  
    session = requests.Session()

    payload = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = session.post(f'{cvat_url}/api/auth/login', json=payload, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()  
    print(response.status_code)  # response is 200
    
    with open(zip_file_path, 'rb') as f:
        files = {
            'annotation_file': (os.path.basename(zip_file_path), f, 'application/zip')
        }

        params = {
            'format': 'CVAT for images 1.1'
        }

        response = session.put(f'{cvat_url}/api/tasks/{task_id}/annotations/', files=files, params=params)
        print(response.status_code) # response is 403

    return response.status_code

Best regards.
The cvat-cli command was able to upload the data.
